# Is Bluetooth's "advertising" mode more secure than "discoverable" mode?

Tags: bluetooth

I understand that there are many security issues associated with Bluetooth's "discoverable" mode, and have avoided it where I can. However new features of many systems (e.g. [Apple's Handoff/Continuity](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/151565/4395)) rely on having Bluetooth's "advertising" mode always on.

Is Bluetooth's "advertising" mode more secure than "discoverable" mode? Are the modes distinct from a security-issues perspective?

Comment: With a specification over 2600 pages long (version 4.1) and dozens of headings related to the two "advertising" modes, it certainly takes more than a casual reading to figure out what one should or shouldn't be careful of!

Answer (score 2):

**Discoverable** is trying to bind connections, while **advertising** is broadcasting with only partial access to BLE protocol stack. Because it never connects, advertising should be more secure wherever applicable. The article below gives a very complete description of advertising.

> > "A non-connectable undirected advertising type signals to scanning
> >     devices that the advertising device will not support a data connection
> >     - only broadcast information."
>
> [Bluetooth LE Advertising Mode](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1280724)